# Importing large sql file to MySql via command line

Tags: mysql, ubuntu

I'm trying to import an sql file of around 300MB to MySql via command line in Ubuntu. I used

```
source /var/www/myfile.sql;
```

Right now it's displaying a seemingly infinite rows of:

```
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.03 sec)
```

However it's been running a little while now. I've not imported a file this large before so I just want to know whether this is normal, if the process stalls or has some errors, will this show up in command line or will this process go on indefinitely?

Thanks

Comment: it will keep running each query in the script until the client crashes or mysql dies, or it runs out of queries to process.

Comment: If the client crashes or mysql dies, do I see this in the command line with an error message or does it just continue infinitely and "appears" like it's running. I just want to know so that if the import drags on for hours and hours I don't waste my time not restarting the process

Comment: if the client crashes, you'll just be back at the shell prompt.

Comment: if the server crashes... not sure, actually. most likely the client would repeatedly try to reconnect and start spewing errors instead of successful query notices.

Answer (score 126, accepted):

You can import .sql file using the standard input like this:

`mysql -u <user> -p<password> <dbname> < file.sql`

**Note:** There shouldn't space between `<-p>` and `<password>`

Reference: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysql-batch-commands.html

**Note for suggested edits:** This answer was slightly changed by suggested edits to use inline password parameter. I can recommend it for scripts but you should be aware that when you write password directly in the parameter (`-p<password>`) it may be cached by a shell history revealing your password to anyone who can read the history file. Whereas `-p` asks you to input password by standard input.

Comment: Oh I see, but is the method I used okay as well or is that wrong

Comment: For your method see reference here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysql-batch-commands.html

Comment: Okay I see. Based on your experience, how long would it take via CLI to import an sql file of 300MB?

Comment: We import files like 4 GB and it takes approx 4-5 minutes depends on the machine. So i guess your file should take max 1 minute. But this is really guessing.

Comment: what.. 4GB takes 4-5 minutes? I'm running a vanilla mysql installation on a windows azure VM with 4 Cores and 7GB of RAM. It's taken 30min and still on going. Do you think there is something wrong here?

Comment: It heavily depends on the structure of database and foreign keys etc. We have large texts but quite simple database structure. Try to use `mysql --verbose` as mentioned in http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysql-batch-commands.html to see what request takes so long.

Comment: Related to this issue again - now I import 6 GB database and it takes ages :-) Like 1 hour already. It really depends on structure of database.

Comment: Since I'm still learning my way around databases, I just found out that an sql file which "appears" to be 300MB in size is actually more close to 1GB in size once imported. It took me like two whole days before it was finished importing. I think I need to tune my MySql setup since it's still the default setup, maybe that will speed up the import next time

Comment: I am curious about your PC spec. Maybe thats the difference. Mine is 16gb ram, Intel 3770K, mysql runs on samsung hdd (not ssd). Because 2 days for 1 GB seems a lot imho.

Comment: I'm running on 4 Cores and 8GB of RAM. I'm not quite sure what sort of CPU or HDD but I'm assuming it's not SDD. This is on a Windows Azure Ubuntu 12.04 virtual machine and they don't really list the specs. May I ask if your MySQL set up is the default config or a tuned version? I've been looking up MySQL tuning tips and I'm thinking of using this https://tools.percona.com/wizard. However I copy pasted the file it provided me on a test server but then I got an error can't access MySQL anymore. Any ideas on the reliability of this?

Comment: On my developer machine I use xampp which has default mysql configuration afaik.

Comment: how long did it take you to import that 6GB file you mentioned?

Comment: I left while it was importing. But definitly it was less than 4 hours.

Comment: Okay basically I looked up some info and researched a bit about mysql tuning. I increased innodb's buffer pool size to 12G and along with some other settings, I've noticed significant speed improvements. The import process has dropped from 20+ hours to 1 hour for my imports, which is great  :)

Comment: This **didn't work**. 

Because my file was 700 gb! On a hosted server that kept timing out.

But it was the right direction. I got SSH access, and then unix `split` the files. `Vim` was still too slow so I used `head` and `tail` to make sure my splits were acceptable. I also had to `cat` append header information/variables. Then ran the command and **it worked**. I did in 45 minutes what took me 9 hours to do by hand! Thank you Martin!

Comment: is this method recommended for huge (~600MB) files with few million rows?

Answer (score 66):

Guys regarding time taken for importing huge files most importantly it takes more time is because default setting of mysql is "autocommit = true", you must set that off before importing your file and then check how import works like a gem...

First open MySQL:

> mysql -u root -p

Then, You just need to do following :

> `mysql>use your_db`
>
> `mysql>SET autocommit=0 ; source the_sql_file.sql ; COMMIT ;`

Comment: That's very cooooool. I like it. A piece of information too. Collect all sql files to one sql file with this: cat *.sql >> all_data.sql That is very usefull. I'm importing 3.5G file now :) Don't forget that tables must be MyIsam.

Comment: Table xxx doesn't exits...why

Comment: Isn't autocommit supposted to get back to `SET autocommit=1 ;` after the import is done?

Comment: No longer has to be MyISAM tables.   Here's the man page for more info and other speed tweaks for unique tables/etc 
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/optimizing-innodb-bulk-data-loading.html

Comment: Hi...how to skip errors, so that import goes on after error... With Force ? How to integrate in SET autocommit=0 ; source the_sql_file.sql ; COMMIT ;     ? --FORCE; ?

Answer (score 8):

+1 to @MartinNuc, you can run the `mysql` client in batch mode and then you won't see the long stream of "OK" lines.

The amount of time it takes to import a given SQL file depends on a lot of things. Not only the size of the file, but the type of statements in it, how powerful your server server is, and how many other things are running at the same time.

@MartinNuc says he can load 4GB of SQL in 4-5 minutes, but I have run 0.5 GB SQL files and had it take 45 minutes on a smaller server.

We can't really guess how long it will take to run your SQL script on your server.

---

Re your comment,

@MartinNuc is correct you can choose to make the mysql client print every statement. Or you could open a second session and run `mysql> SHOW PROCESSLIST` to see what's running. But you probably are more interested in a "percentage done" figure or an estimate for how long it will take to complete the remaining statements.

Sorry, there is no such feature. The mysql client doesn't know how long it will take to run later statements, or even how many there are.  So it can't give a meaningful estimate for how much time it will take to complete.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Bill, does the command mentioned by Martin provide some sort of process display or anything? I can't really test right now since I would have to cancel the current import.

Comment: `mysql --verbose` to see every command. Mentioned in the reference http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysql-batch-commands.html

Comment: Bill you can have percentage complete feature using Pipe View Utility.... e.g `sudo pv -i 1 -p -t -e DB.sql | mysql -uDB_USER -p DBANAME`

Comment: @abhi, that's a great tip! It assumes that each of the statements in the DB.sql file are close to the same cost, but that's not a bad assumption in most cases.

Comment: @abhi, except I frequently compress my .sql files, so I'd have to know the uncompressed size to get a progress bar: `bunzip2 DB.gz.bz2 | pv -i 1 -p  -t -e -s 2758819477 | mysql ...`

Answer (score 1):

The solution I use for large sql restore is a mysqldumpsplitter script. I split my sql.gz into individual tables. then load up something like mysql workbench and process it as a restore to the desired schema.

Here is the script
https://github.com/kedarvj/mysqldumpsplitter

And this works for larger sql restores, my average on one site I work with is a 2.5gb sql.gz file, 20GB uncompressed, and ~100Gb once restored fully

Answer (score 0):

**Importing large sql file to MySql via command line**

1. first download file .
2. paste file on home.
3. use following command in your terminals(CMD)
4. Syntax:
   mysql -u username -p databsename < file.sql

Example:
 mysql -u root -p aanew < aanew.sql

Answer (score 0):

I imported last days a large sql file which is bigger than 11GB. In my case, no need to all database. I only imported some tables I need. So maybe following solution works for someone;

```
grep -A 200 ‘CREATE TABLE `xyz_table’ sql_file_path > new_light_sql_file_path.sql
```

Once you create light sql file you can import it easily as following cmd.

mysql -u username -p(pass) databasename < new_light_sql_file_path.sql