# I want to store a .sql file into shell variable which contains nearly 500 lines

Tags: string, shell, variables

I am new to shell scripting and i want to store a .sql file into a variable without loosing its formatting which contains around 500 lines.

Thanks for the help in advance.

Thanks,
Sunil

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Importing large sql file to MySql via command line](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19483087/importing-large-sql-file-to-mysql-via-command-line)

Comment: I dont want to insert the sql script in to the database but instead store in a variable for further use in the same shell