# Website migration from a server with cPanel to one without?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, migration, cpanel, database-migration

I want to migrate some websites (files and databases) from a server with cPanel accounts to a new server running on Ubuntu where is not cPanel.
Which would be the quickest and simple method?

Thank you in advance !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the server doesn't have any control panel, you have only manual migration option.

- Setup a web server and add websites.
- Assign separate home directory to each website.
- Setup database server and migrate databases.
- You can generate full cPanel backup and then extract it on new server. You will get web contents from homedir folder and MySQL.

Comment: Thank you Kailash !

Answer (score 0):

The quickest way is to do a complete backup, and download the file.  It should be in the root directory for that user.

The path and filename looks like:

/home/username/backup-*todaysdate*_username.tar.gz

Download that, and extract the files.

You'll want the /homedir (which is where the website is) and the /mysql folder contains a backup of the databse in .sql format.

Then copy everything up to your new server, and you'll have to extract the mysql database into mysql using the MYSQL CLI.  Here's some instructions on that -> [Importing large sql file to MySql via command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19483087/importing-large-sql-file-to-mysql-via-command-line)

Comment: Thank you Howard !